# On-click event not opening in same tab/window on a mouseover zoom image

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites

I am trying to open a web page on same tab/window on-clicking a zoom-over image. I tried `_self` but it is not working. Also, I am using Google Sites to develop a simple website. It seems easy but not getting the answer and I'm unable to solve the issue. Attaching my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom[href] {
  padding: 2px;
  transition: transform .3s;
  width: 150px;
  height: 81px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.3); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px; /* remove scrollbar space /
background: transparent; / optional: just make scrollbar invisible /
}
/ optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable
function openRequestedPopup(url, windowName) {
  if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed) {
    windowObjectReference = window.open(url, windowName, "_self");
  } else {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
  };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="zoom">
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="openRequestedPopup(this.href, this.target); return false;">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="Our Performance" styles="width:100%">
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my current situation:
[image]

And this is what i am expecting:

[image]

Comment: You're calling window.open(). Set `window.location` instead: `window.location = url;` is all you need. However here's a better solution: https://jsfiddle.net/aLhbw0x1/

Comment: What do you mean with `opens in the same div/block`? That sounds as if an `iframe` is involved.

Comment: @t.niese I mean in tags <div>. So it opens in the same piece of block in a web page and not in the same tab.

Comment: That does not make sense. If you click on a link it will load that page in the same window or a different one, but not in any existing element. That will only happen if page on which the link is, is loaded within an `iframe` and then it will load in this iframe.

Comment: @t.niese I am using google site to embed the code. Does that mean google site uses iframe to set my embedded code in a particular block?

Comment: I don’t know. Check it yourself using the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried your code, but the hyperlink opens in new window. Pl check my edited post for further information.

Comment: Browsers handle things differently when the window contains a 3rd party site in it.

Comment: You can see that my fiddle works fine. It's clear what you're trying to do, and the code in my fiddle does exactly that, as far as I can tell. If you're still getting a new window, you didn't properly implement my solution.

Comment: @ChrisG Nevermind. I found that Google site has a default iframe setup that allows all the external link to open in different window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you intend to open a popup inside your page when the user is clicking on it. This can be achieved as follows:

## 1. Create an iframe

You will need to create an `iframe` like this:

```
<iframe id="mypopup" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

## 2. Create a function that opens it with a URL

```
function openIFrame(url) {
    let myPopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
    mypopup.style.display = "block";
    mypopup.src = url;
}
```

## 3. Have an onclick that executes it

Something like

```
onclick="openIFrame(this.href); return false;"
```

in your anchor.